# touch on uiimage in uitableview section does not get detected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I want to add a gesture recognizer to a `UIImageView` in a `UITableViewCell`.

I've subclassed this cell, and implemented the gesture code, but it does not seem to be working .

This is the code for my subclassed `.m` file:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
  self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
  if (self) {
    [self.settingsView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didRecognizeTapOnSettings)];
    [tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [self.settingsView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
  }
  return self;
}
```

I'm using initwithcoder since I'm using storyboards, and that seems to be working far better than initwithframe. For some odd reason, `didRecognizeTapOnSettings` does not get called. I've set the delegate of the `UIGestureRecognizer` in my `.h` file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBOutlets are not yet set inside an init method, so self.settingsView is going to be nil. Move the code you have in the if(self) block to awakeFromNib, and then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
[tap setMinimumPressDuration:0.1f];
```

then you said you are setting your delegate for the gesture then if you are planning to use your delegate methods for the tapGesture you should set the delegate to self.

```
tap.delegate = self;
```

What's the hierarchy in your views? Your UITableViewCell might be catching the tap event instead of your UIImageView. As an experiment try to disable the userInteractions in the UITableViewCell contentView I'm assuming that you added the UIImageView in the contentView of your cell.

Let me know if that worked